# Add SVG Data as background in before style

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to add a vector image (svg) into the background css of a before element. However I need to be able to change the colour of this path within CSS also.

This is what I have got at the moment, i'm using LESS to compile the CSS, so as you can see there is a variable in there which should change to the colour when I compile.

```
background: url(data:image/svg+xml,%20%20%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20512%20512%22%3E%0A%20%20%09%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23@test-color%22%20d%3D%22M49.916%2C1.295C49.355%2C0.484%2C48.417%2C0%2C47.406%2C0S45.457%2C0.484%2C44.9%2C1.291c-3.095%2C4.446-30.231%2C43.93-30.231%2C60.784%0A%09%09c0%2C18.052%2C14.686%2C32.737%2C32.737%2C32.737c18.05%2C0%2C32.737-14.687%2C32.737-32.737C80.143%2C45.22%2C53.007%2C5.737%2C49.916%2C1.295z%0A%09%09%20M47.33%2C82.719c-0.402%2C2.166-2.293%2C3.68-4.42%2C3.68c-0.272%2C0-0.549-0.025-0.826-0.076c-15.646-2.902-20.04-18.395-20.178-26.18%0A%09%09c-0.044-2.484%2C1.935-4.534%2C4.42-4.578c0.026-0.001%2C0.054-0.001%2C0.081-0.001c2.443%2C0%2C4.445%2C1.954%2C4.497%2C4.405%0A%09%09c0.017%2C0.646%2C0.539%2C15.225%2C12.822%2C17.504C46.17%2C77.926%2C47.783%2C80.274%2C47.33%2C82.719z%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%09%3C%2Fsvg%3E) no-repeat 50% 50%;
```

This `@test-color` is replaced with the colour defined in the document, but this does not work within the path data, is there a way I can just change the fill colour in the CSS whilst having this SVG as a background image?

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: What you have is what there is.

Comment: Turns out the answer isn't no considering the below answer works.... lol!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean this? `@{variable-name}`

```
@test-color: #f0f0f0;
div {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,....#@{test-color}...") no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```